# Filtering text out of a BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, text, file-io, buffer

Currently working on a project which requires me to read in file input of over 50k lines. I am currently using the BufferedReader class to read in the input and present the data in a text area. Currently, the application just reproduces the file in my own HMI similar to a text editor, however where I would like to differ is that there are certain starting words for each line that I would like to not be presented in the text area... I believe my lack of experience with buffers is responsible for my problems. I have tried implementing code along the following lines:

```
private void insertSyrFile(BufferedReader buffer, JFileChooser chooser) throws IOException{
    String line;
    //reader = "\n";
    try{
        reader = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
        buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
        if (!line.startsWith("Elaborating"))
            origSyrTextFeild.read(buffer, null);

    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }       
}
```

This code was implemented with the following button event handler:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    syrFile.openFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());

    try {
        insertSyrFile(buffer, chooser);     //origSyrTextFeild.setText(syrFile.readFileLine());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ParsingAppMainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
}
```

... using this code, even though I have if statement to check for a string, the original file is still reproduced with no processing on the file. I am still a beginner in java, however if someone understands what my goal is and has any insight I'd appreciate any ideas!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may use " origSyrTextFeild.append(line);" instead of " origSyrTextFeild.read(buffer, null);". Because the if statement checks the "line" but "read" method get contents from the original buffer.